# OMP Распараллеливание вычисления

Tags: c++, openmp

Помогите понять, почему не работает параллельность в данном примере? Пытаюсь разобраться в OMP, но судя по тестам, параллельности нет. Взял из интернета алгоритм и пытаюсь прикрутить к нему параллельность хоть какую-то.

```
//Программа демонстрирует поиск минимума функции нескольких переменных методом наискорейшего спуска
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>

//Структура вектор
//Содержит количество переменных исходной функции
struct vector
{
        double x, y;
};
//Исходная функция
double fx(vector x)
{
    return 100 * (x.x * x.x + x.y * x.y);
}

//Градиент исходной функции
//Также для нахождения градиента можно использовать численные методы
vector gradient(vector x)
{
    vector grad;
    grad.x = 200 * x.x;
    grad.y = 200 * x.y;
    return grad;
}
//Вычисление одномерной функции для нахождения шага методом золотого сечения
double MakeSimplefx(double x, vector grad, vector xj)
{
    vector buffer;
    buffer.x = xj.x - x * grad.x;
    buffer.y = xj.y - x * grad.y;
    return fx(buffer);
}
//Метод золотого сечения для нахождения шага (lambda)
double GoldenSelection(double a, double b, double eps, vector gradient, vector x)
{
    const double fi = 1.6180339887;
    double x1, x2;
    double y1, y2;
    x1 = b - ((b - a) / fi);
    x2 = a + ((b - a) / fi);
    y1 = MakeSimplefx(x1, gradient, x);
    y2 = MakeSimplefx(x2, gradient, x);
    while (std::abs(b - a) > eps)
    {
        if (y1 <= y2)
        {
            b = x2;
            x2 = x1;
            x1 = b - ((b - a) / fi);
            y2 = y1;
            y1 = MakeSimplefx(x1, gradient, x);
        }
        else
        {
            a = x1;
            x1 = x2;
            x2 = a + ((b - a) / fi);
            y1 = y2;
            y2 = MakeSimplefx(x2, gradient, x);
        }
    }
    return (a + b) / 2;
}
//Функция вычисления нового приближения
vector Calculate(vector x, vector gradient, double lambda)
{
    vector buffer;
    buffer.x = x.x - lambda * gradient.x;
    buffer.y = x.y - lambda * gradient.y;
    return buffer;
}
//Метод наискорейшего спуска
vector GradDown(vector x, double eps)
{
    vector current = x;
    vector last;
    do
    {
        last = current; //Запоминаем предыдущее значение
        vector grad = gradient(current); //Вычисляем градиент
        double lambda = GoldenSelection(0, 0.05, eps, grad, current); //Находим шаг вычислений методом золотого сечения
        current = Calculate(current, grad, lambda); //Вычисляем новое приближение
    }while (std::abs(fx(current) - fx(last)) > eps); //Проверяем условие
    return current; //Возвращаем результат
}

//Тело главной функции
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    vector x;
    double eps;
    int THREAD_NUMBER;
    std::cout << "Введите кол-во потоков.\n";
    std::cin >> THREAD_NUMBER;
    omp_set_num_threads(THREAD_NUMBER);
    int arraysize;
    std::cout << "Введите кол-во векторов.\n";
    std::cin >> arraysize;
    vector *arr = new vector[arraysize];
    double time = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(THREAD_NUMBER)
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
    {
        x.x = rand() % 15+0;
        x.y = rand() % 15+0;
        eps = rand() % 1 + 0.000001;
            arr[i] = GradDown(x, eps);
        //#pragma omp critical
        //{
        //}
    }
    time = omp_get_wtime() - time;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
    {
        //std::cout << "\nРезультат: х = " << arr[i].x << " y = "<<arr[i].y;
    }
    std::cout << "\nВремя расчёта: " << time;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем внутри for идет обращение к общим переменным `x` и `eps`?

Comment: @user7860670 для каждого вектора нужны свои уникальные x и eps

Answer (score 1):

Как говорится, дурак, он и в Африке дурак. Смотрит в книгу, а видит книгу.
Никогда не пытайтесь лезть в новую тему, не прочитав документацию полностью.
Нужно было просто включить openmp в свойствах проекта.
Будет мне урок.